# Display settings always reset when switching between Join Display/External Only/Built-in Only on Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, 23.04

My display settings always reset to the initial settings when I switch between Join Display/External Only/Built-in Only.

Even if I select the same option, e.g. from Join Display to Join Display, the display settings may reset to the default settings.

Is there a solution so that I don't have to do this every time I switch the display options?

Here are my device details:

[Device details screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZk3S.png)